# No puedo hacer funcionar el range en mi modulo

Tags: python-3.x

En el modulo pongo print(range(5)), pero solo me aparece 0, 5 y en el libro sale 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Ya lo convertí en variable y cambie el paréntesis por corchete pero no me sale, también lo convertí en variable pero no me aparece. Acá dejo el código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def del_uno_al_cinco():
  print(range(5))

if __name__ == '__main__':

 print("Soy un script")
 print("Esto no se muestra como módulo")

 del_uno_al_cinco()

input()
```

Y acá pongo como me aparece cuando lo imprimo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usa `print(*range(5))` dentro de tu función.

Answer (score 1):

Entre los tipos básicos de Python se encuentra la *secuencia*, que viene en tres variedades: listas, tuplas y rangos (*range*).

`range()` no es una función, es una secuencia inmutable. Siendo una secuencia, `range()` soporta la mayoría de las operaciones usadas con listas y tuplas, exceptuando aquellas que no tienen sentido dado que `range()` es inmutable.

Cosas que se pueden hacer con `range()`.

```
r = range(0, 5)
min(r) => 0
max(r) => 5
len(r) => 5
r[1:2] => range(1, 2)
```

El operador `*` se usa delante de una expresión en una llamada a función para convertir un iterable en sus valores explícitos. Por tanto,

```
print(*r)
```

primero convierte `r` en sus valores, y luego llama a la función con ellos.

```
print(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

En el siguiente caso parece no haber llamada a función:

```
lista = [*r]
```

pero el uso de "[]" es equivalente a `list()`

```
lista = list(*r) => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```